# אדנ-י יהו-ה - Significance to these two names of God used together?

Tags: tanach, shemos-sacred-names

In many places in Tanach, God is referred to as אדנ-י יהו-ה.

For example: David's speech in [Shmuel II, 7:18-29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.7.18-29) includes seven such references.

What is the significance for God being addressed in this way? What does the combination of these specific names of God teach us when they are combined in this way?

Comment: I wrote the title as I did because that is the way that it is commonly pronounced and I felt weird writing שם המפורש in the title. The text of the question gives the specifics.

Comment: The old title was ambiguous. If you don't want the Shemot in the title and can't think of a better way to disambiguate, I guess it's fine to just remove them and readers will have to wait to read the post to know what these refers to.